# XML > XML Files > Editor > Content assist is not found in eclipse RAD 7.0

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rad

**XML > XML Files > Editor > Content assist** is not found in eclipse RAD 7.0. I have a xml content assist plugin which gives the suggestions based upon some references. 
 But in RAD, I am not finding content assist. 
I need suggestions, whether I have to upgrade to the latest version of RAD, or does any URL site is there for installing xml content assist plugin.

Comment: "I have a xml content assist plugin which gives the suggestions based upon some references." What plug-in is that? RAD already provides one.

Comment: I am overriding eclipse provided plugin